# Story in which it was suggested that Dolphin language uses echoes from objects as nouns?

Tags: story-identification

I think this story was written after 1960 and before 1980, probably 1970s. This idea, that dolphin reproduce the sounds that echo from objects and quite naturally use these sounds to represent the object I think is believed now but it had its origin in this story.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but isn't it the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy? If anything, this would be the book/movie I'd expect it to be in.

Comment: I sure don't remember that detail in HGTTG and I am pretty sure that is not the book. It is story or book where dolphins are the main focus, not mentioned in passing like in Guide.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds vaguely like *[Startide Rising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Startide_Rising)*, published in 1983 as part of the Uplift series by David Brin.

Comment: Does *Startide Rising* match the OP's description better than the average intelligent-dolphins story? Is it "suggested that Dolphin language uses echoes from objects as nouns"?

Comment: Definitely not the right time frame and I believe it was not a book but a single story.

Comment: @user14111: its been a while, but I do recall the dolphins sometimes communicating using sound-images as well as language.