# Book that talked about the language of dolphins (before the science confirmed it)?

Tags: story-identification

In a book written probably between 1960 and 1980 a science fiction author wrote of dolphin language consisting of reproducing the signals that a dolphin (or other whale, I forget) gets back when it uses its clicks to look at an object.

This sounded pretty compelling to me at the time -- not so different than humans using drawing to communicate except probably all dolphin do this naturally.

I believe this has been substantiated -- researchers I think can compare sounds dolphin make to the sounds returned by an object.

**The interesting thing is, the science fiction author may have anticipated this research by many years and I wonder if anyone can tell me what author and what book/story?**

Comment: I don't have time right now to pull it out and look, but could this be *Startide Rising* by Brin?  It's certainly the first novel that pops to mind when you talk about dolphin languages.  (The fins mostly spoke Trinary, because they needed it to think, but there are extensive descriptions of Primal especially when Akki is fighting Katha-Jon.)

Comment: No, not Brin, earlier. Does not mean he did not use the idea.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/154855/82909. Can you look at the answers and see if any are correct? (If it reminds you of any details, add them to the question too.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162238/story-in-which-it-was-suggested-that-dolphin-language-uses-echoes-from-objects-a (unanswered)

Comment: @DavidW: it looks like a dupe even with the time frame (which is why Brin stories are not what I am looking for) if this is a dupe, should i delete and hope the question u found will be answered?

Comment: No, don't delete this.  That user hasn't been seen in a couple of years, so even if that question collects a correct answer it might not get accepted.

Comment: Ian Watson's *The Jonah Kit* (1976) fits the timeframe in question, but all I have to go on that it might fit is part of a [review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/512238051?book_show_action=true&from_review_page=1) that mentions a sperm whale and "The idea of sound and communication is repeated and reflected via the whistling codes of the Mexicans, the clicking of the Jonah kit, the clicking messages from the stars "

Comment: @DavidW: this page plus the vaguest memory of my own supports this book u suggested: https://books.google.com/books?id=u1rXKH-SRHYC&pg=PA320&lpg=PA320&dq=%22the+jonah+kit%22+scifi+echolocation+watson&source=bl&ots=LDQMLkcQd0&sig=ACfU3U2_HEwFuTF9-cx53khzAPxc78DVpQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQgKzR1q_tAhUNGzQIHVIZBGcQ6AEwAHoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22the%20jonah%20kit%22%20scifi%20echolocation%20watson&f=false

Comment: In real life, [John C. Lilly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_C._Lilly) worked on dolphin communication during the 1950s and 60s, and convinced many people at the time. However, his research is now considered to be flawed.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron: firstly, i can find nothing about Lilly's research being flawed, secondly, what would that have to do with the question I asked?

Comment: Perhaps _Day of the Dolphin_?

Comment: @NomadMaker: I can look up titles with the word "dolphin" in it all day -- does the book have the specific idea i mentioned in it?

Comment: Voice of the Dolphins - Leo Szilard? The story focuses on a research institute in Vienna where a pod of captured dolphins is kept in a tank. The scientists learn to communicate with the dolphins, quickly realizing that they are far more intelligent than human beings. For example, the dolphins invent a strain of algae that is both a cheap source of protein and a drug that suppresses fertility in women, thus solving the problems of world hunger and over-population in a single stroke.

Comment: @releseabe Your question was, "The interesting thing is, the science fiction author may have anticipated this research by many years and I wonder if anyone can tell me what author and what book/story?" Since, in real life, Lilly began his research on dolphin communication in the 1950s, this would precede any science fiction written "between 1960 and 1980." Whether the research was flawed or not is indeed irrelevant to your question, but a matter of possible interest to readers. But if the science fiction preceded the science, you will have to look for it in earlier works than you thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on a positive comment, I'm going to suggest this might be [*The Jonah Kit*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?5211) (1976) by Ian Watson.  One of the threads of the book concerns a sperm whale that has had the mind pattern of an astronaut imposed on it so the whale can communicate with humans and be controlled/directed.  (The whale seems to be forced to do things it would not wish to, like surfacing periodically to report on what it has seen in the deeps.)

Sound, echoes, and sound pictures seem to be a large part of how the whale is portrayed to think and communicate with its kind.

> He compares his mental model of a Ten-Arms reaching up to wrap suckers round his forehead-a painful memory, this!-with one of a Steel cruising a deep trench: a pregnant Steel, with a dozen steel foetuses upright in womb pods along her back.  (Curiously rigid and lifeless, though, her little ones-for all that there's a tiny heart tick present in each of them...!)

> He searches peaks and canyons far below, **building him-self an exact sound model of the crags and depths**, the water density gradients, deep scattering layers of crustaceans, jellyfish, siphonophores, that billow out around the mountains in faint veils.  A percussion of croaks, drummings and grunts stipples his **echo map** too, from other small food beasts making noises.

> When Seven gather nose to nose and brow to brow in slack water, waving their flukes to stay in place, their seven melons of liquid wax cut off from the sea-world and look inward, not outward; become a closed system for their clicking thoughts.  The pure **ideas burst-pulsing in each other's melons echo, re-echo, combine and interfere**... weave patterns larger than the pattern of an idea carved in oil-wax in any single brow.  So the Glyphs of Awareness are born-which only a new Star-Gathering can fully open up again, which nonetheless finger on in the individual's memory in the meanwhile as foci.

Comment: i would like to see what others say but this could be it. now i am wondering if i read the book itself or just a review. maybe i will try to see if ian watson thinks he came up with the idea. without powerful computers i think the experiments would be hard so idea came first.

Answer (score 1):

I am throwing in the book the movie "The Day of the Dolphin" was based upon.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_of_the_Dolphin_(book)

> The Day of the Dolphin (Un animal doué de raison – lit. A Sentient
> Animal) is a 1967 science fiction thriller novel by French novelist
> Robert Merle. The plot concerns dolphins that are trained to
> communicate with humans, and their use in warfare. The central
> character is a government scientist with similar ideas to those of
> John C. Lilly.
>
> The English translation of the novel was published in 1969 with the
> title The Day of the Dolphin, which is not a literal translation of
> the French title. The novel was the basis for the 1973 film The Day
> of the Dolphin, though the film's plot was significantly different
> from that of the book, even in inconsequential details. For instance,
> in the book, the dolphins are named Ivan ("the terrible") and Bessie
> and call themselves Fa and Bi; in the film, they are instead named
> Alpha and Beta and call themselves Fa and Be.

It fits the timeframe. I have not read the book, but I remember the movie and there were discussion about the dolphins' language, even if in the movie they made the dolphin understand English.

Comment: In the book, also, the dolphins are taught to understand English, and IIRC speak an approximation of it. Anyone who has read the English translation of the book is likely to remember a scene which contained a single stream-of-consciousness type sentence that went on for over a page. It's hard to forget.

Answer (score 0):

[*Dolphin Island*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolphin_Island_(novel)) by Arthur C.Clarke, 1963

> Late one night (in the world of the future), a giant cargo hovership makes an emergency landing somewhere in the middle of the United States and an enterprising teenager named Johnny Clinton stows away on it. A few hours later, the craft crashes into the Pacific Ocean. The crew ("even the ship's cat") is offloaded onto lifeboats, leaving Johnny (who, as a stowaway, was not on the ship's manifest) adrift in the flotsam from the wreckage. His life is saved by the "People of the Sea"—dolphins. A school of these fantastic creatures guides him to an island on Australia's Great Barrier Reef. Johnny becomes involved with the work of a strange and fascinating research community where a brilliant professor tries to communicate with dolphins. Johnny learns skindiving and survives a typhoon—only to risk his life again, immediately afterwards, to get medical help for the people on the island.

Comment: Can you expand on why this matches?

Comment: kids' book, does not feel right (but nice if ACC came up with the idea) but I don't think I've read it.

Comment: This is likely to be the right answer. From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolphin_Island_(novel)): "Johnny becomes involved with the work of a strange and fascinating research community where a brilliant professor tries to communicate with dolphins."

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron: what? why?

Comment: @releseabe I've read *Dolphin Island*. It does revolve around scientists (Professor Kazan) figuring out how to communicate with dolphins, but not using their echolocation as you described in the question.

Comment: @releseabe _Dolphin Island_ is a well-known novel from the early 1960s that deals with dolphin communication. I don't have the book at hand and don't know whether it deals with echolocation; I read it too long ago. Your question doesn't make it entirely clear whether you are looking for an early work of fiction concerning echolocation only, communication only, or both: Which is it?

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron: it is 100% clear. I am done here.